# Append #hashtag to link in HTML on the fly

Tags: javascript, jquery, hashtag

I have a nav, each link in the nav just appends a hashtag on the existing URL when clicked, for live filtering, etc. with the use of jQuery.

I want to append the SAME current hashtag to a series of links within a div further down the page.

For example, I've clicked "work" and my URL now looks like:

```
http://www.domain.com/page.html#work
```

I have a series of links in the page:

```
<div id="links">
<ul>
  <li><a href="http://www.domain.com/link1">Link1</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.domain.com/link2">Link2</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.domain.com/link3">Link3</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.domain.com/link4">Link4</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

These links within the div#links need to be updated on the fly to append #work on all the URL's so that when clicked the hashtag is appended.

Is this possible? Does this make sense?

Comment: I think we all answered with differing variations on how we read your question. I thought you wanted to append the link text as the hash (e.g. www.com#link1), Chigley thinks you want to append #work to them all (valid interpretation), and I'm not sure what Adam thinks (He just posted a few seconds ago, so I haven't read it). Maybe a slight clarification would help us out.

Comment: @Jud - would have +1'd your comment if it wasn't for the misspelling of chigley :P (You're not the first, and certainly won't be the last! Don't get why it happens so often...)

Comment: @chigley - haha, thats what I get for always scanning everything instead of really "reading" it. Gets me in trouble all the time.

Comment: @Jud- I assumed the same as chigley, with the slight the difference that my code takes the hashtag from the url the user is currently at.

Comment: ha, and bobince gets the upvote. ;)

Comment: Wow. Thank you everyone for your answers. galambalazs seems to be the closest. I should have included my nav as well. The links in the nav only link to #work, #home, etc. As these hashtags are appended to the URL when clicked I need to update the series of links in the list item with this same current hashtag.

Comment: Sorry, quick clarification on my last comment. I need to update the series of links with the current hash tag at the END of it's URL.

Comment: Ok, galambalazs had it spot on and everything is working great now. Again, thanks for your minds on this :)

Comment: @Robert - next time, **make your question clearer**. Loads of us were trying to guess what behaviour you wanted the code to exhibit. galambalazs did a very good job of working it out, because until reading the above comment, I still thought you wanted `#work` appended to all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should attach a `click` event handler for links in `#nav` and change links in `#links` accordingly. **[[See it in action](http://jsbin.com/ociso3/)]**

**Javascript**

```
$("#nav a").click(function() {
  $("#links a").each(function() {
    this.href = this.href.split("#")[0] + "#" + window.location.hash;
  });
});​
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="nav">  
  <a href="#work">work</a> - 
  <a href="#school">school</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Oooh. i see this is working on your example exactly as I was looking for. However, there are other times when i see the hashtag update is one off... as in i click #work and it shows home, then i click home and it shows #school. It seems about 50/50 on my end?

Comment: Update. This seems to be working amazing on my page now. Thank you so much!

Comment: `window.location.hash` already contains "#" for me. Can I rely on this, and remove the `"#" + ` from your solution?

Answer (score 4):

Use the `hash` property of links to set the fragment identifier without messing around with the rest of the `href`:

```
$('#links a').each(function() {
    this.hash= location.hash;
});​​​​​​​
```

Answer (score 2):

The jQuery code below will select [each](http://api.jquery.com/each/) `<a>` [within](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/) `<li>` [within](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/) the `<div>` [with the id](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) of `links` and [change its href attribute](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to be the same as its current value but with [the hash of the current page appended to it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location).

```
$("div#links li a").each(
  function(index, element){
     $(this).attr('href',$(this).attr('href') + window.location.hash)
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#links a').each(function() {
        $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href')+'#work');
    });​​​​​​​
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#links li a').each(function()
{
    $(this).attr('href', '#' + $(this).html());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use livequery plugin : http://plugins.jquery.com/project/livequery and the documentation is here http://brandonaaron.net/code/livequery/docs

edit:
Live Query utilizes the power of jQuery selectors by binding events or firing callbacks for matched elements auto-magically, even after the page has been loaded and the DOM updated

```
 $("#links a").livequery('click',function(event) {
                 $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href')+'#work');
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("a[href]").click(function(){
   var href = $(this).attr('href');
   var ind = href.indexOf('#');
   if ( ind != -1 ) {
    var hash = href.substring(ind+1);
    $("div#links li a").each(function() {
     var myHref = $(this).attr('href');
     var myInd = myHref('#');
     if ( myInd != -1 ) {
      myHref = myHref.substring(0, myInd);
     }
     $(this).attr('href', myHref + hash)
    });
   }
  });
```

Comment: Looks like galambalazs was a little quicker then me. Our answers are very similiar. His javascript approach using split does make the code easier to follow -- much shorter code.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this page for complete demo with hasgtag,ajax and html history API http://www.amitpatil.me/create-gmail-like-app-using-html5-history-api-and-hashbang/